# Swift table view not showing contents

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to give a go at swift, and looked at several tutorials. I tried to implement a TableView.

Here is my code :

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController:  UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var items: [String] = ["lol1", "lol2", "lol3"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!

        cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("You selected cell #\(items[indexPath.row])!")
    }

}
```

MY IBOutlet is connect to the tableview I inserted in the storyboard.

When I run it, I have a TableView, but it's missing contents.

From what I gathered through some (more or less outdated) tutorials, I shouldn't have anything more to do, what am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you set dataSource and Deleagte methods of TableView?

use this code

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
```

Comment: That's an excellent question, the tutorials I watched are probably too outdated

Comment: @beauchette may be, you can try it after setting dataSource or delegate method of tableView.

Comment: oh yeah it works now. I know it's not the place to argue about this kind of decision, but swift is moving too fast. swiftui is moving too fast too. A lot of resources I find are outdated, it's really annoying.

Comment: @beauchette That's not a question of *moving Swift*. Driving the table view is the same since Swift 1.

Answer (score 1):

2 possible reasons:

1. If the cell is designed as prototype cell you **must not** register the cell.
2. `dataSource` and `delegate` of the table view must be connected to the controller in Interface Builder or set in code.

Comment: the tutorials I used didn't use 2. it now works. And as for 1., I remember it worked like in objective c too, but that it worked anyway, I will use custom cells in the future anyway. Thank you for reminding that.

Comment: Then the controller in the tutorials is a subclass of `UITableViewController` which has connected data source and delegate by default.

Comment: it is declared like that : class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource . Maybe the tutorial in itself doesn't work at all.

Comment: As I wrote, you can connect data source and delegate in Interface Builder or in code but you have to anyway when using `UIViewController`